# Vim - How to replace a newline with the string "\n"

Tags: regular-expression, vim

In vim, I want to replace newlines with the literal string `\n`.

For example, if I open a file that contains this text:

```
This is line one
This is line two
```

I want to replace the newlines and have the following:

```
This is line one\nThis is line two
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does it need to be done in `vim`? Can it just use `sed` on the file itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the replace part of your substition with `\`

```
:1,$-1s/\n/\\n
```

Breakdown

```
:            start an ex command
1,$-1        over a range from the first line till the last but one
s/           substitute
\n           all newlines
/            with
\\n          literal string \n
```

Comment: This will add an extra `\n` after the last line of the file. In the example given, it will end in `two\n`. (This might be fine, but it's slightly different from what was asked in the question.) Also, it would be good to start with a `:` to indicate this is an Ex command.

Comment: @filbranden - You are right offcourse, the last line doesn't necessarely has a newline but in most cases it would. I have adjusted the answer to address the last newline.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
:1,$-s/\n/\\n
```

This won't replace at the end of the file, so:

```
This is line one\nThis is line two\nThis is line three
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here, there's no `/` in between `-` and `s`, so that makes this command fail. Also, you don't need `/g` here since there's only one `\n` to match per line... Kudos on handling the last line correctly with `$-` though!!!

Comment: @filbranden Thanks! I edited the answer.